# send multple formats as response in the same endpoint in nest js (picture and json)

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I just begin with nest js and I have an endpoint where I want to return a picture and a json in the same response. I would like to know if possible to do that?

This is my code :

```
 @Get('/:id')
    async getObjectById(@Param('id') id: number,@Res() res){
        const object =  this.objectService.findById(id);
         const photo = await object.then(data=>data.photo);

        return of(res.send( await object),res.sendFile(join(process.cwd(), 'uploads/profileimages/'+photo))) 
    }
```

I would like to know if there is any possiblitie to return both responses

In postman I receive the json but not the picture and vice versa if I add the picture to return first.

[image]

in the console I receive this logs

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: HTTP request are signle request single response, you don't send two responses ever for a request. You could send the picture as part of the JSON, but that could make the JSON rather large in size. Why do you want to send an image and the JSON? What's the use case here?

Comment: In fact the picture will be linked to the json, with the id id which is present in the request I want to get back the json and the picture

Comment: that use case is not good, I think you can upload that image to somewhere, or use static asset and respond client the link to that image, 1 response with 2 things is just non sense to me

Comment: indeed i can separate this in two separate endpoints and check get the json and the picture separately. But I was wondorering if we can get both directly, to avoid having two differents endpoints